# async/await and opening a FileStream?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, .net-4.5

I came across the following question when trying to determine if I was using the `Stream` methods such as `ReadAsync` and `CopyToAsync` correctly:
[C# 4.5 file read performance sync vs async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18331349/c-sharp-4-5-file-read-performance-sync-vs-async)

In this question I read the following in the accepted answer:

> Most notably, your "async" test does not use async I/O; with file
>   streams, **you have to explicitly open them as asynchronous or else
>   you're just doing synchronous operations on a background thread.**

In his asynchronous IO code he was using the following to open the `FileStream` 'asynchronously':

```
var file = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 4096, true)
```

So I was wondering if you intend to use methods such as `CopyToAsync` whether you should open the underlying `FileStream` as shown above?, as opposed to doing something simple like the following:

```
File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open)
```

Which is how the example in the actual documentation for `CopyToAsync` demonstrates opening the underlying `FileStream`:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh159084(v=vs.110).aspx

If it does not matter which way the underlying `FileStream` is opened, what does the `useAsync` parameter of the `FileStream` constructor do?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> So I was wondering if you intend to use methods such as CopyToAsync whether you should open the underlying FileStream as shown above?

Yes. The reason is mostly historical.

First, on Windows, [`HANDLE`s (including file handles) must be opened/created explicitly with an asynchronous flag if you want to do asynchronous (`OVERLAPPED`) operations on them](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686358(v=vs.85).aspx).

However, [the old Windows 95/98/ME line *only* supported asynchronous operations on serial port and IOCTL (device driver) handles](http://www.webcitation.org/6hHLFuCGI). Asynchronous I/O on *disk files* wasn't supported on that platform line. And [the original .NET *did* support 98/ME](https://stackoverflow.com/a/198925/263693), so the original `FileStream` just used synchronous I/O. I *think* (but am not absolutely sure) that [APM methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963(v=vs.110).aspx) (like `FileStream.BeginRead`) on Win98/ME were probably just implemented using the so-called ["asynchronous delegates"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e08f6yc(v=vs.110).aspx) (which just execute a synchronous method like `FileStream.Read` on a thread pool thread).

So, that's the historical reason why file stream handles were *not* opened with the asynchronous flag by default.

> Which is how the example in the actual documentation for CopyToAsync demonstrates

Unfortunately, a lot of the MSDN examples are rather poor quality. They're OK if you approach them from the perspective of "here's an example of how to call this specific method", but not so great from the perspective of "here's an example of production-quality code that uses this method".

Answer (score 7):

> So I was wondering if you intend to use methods such as CopyToAsync whether you should open the underlying FileStream as shown above, as opposed to doing something simple like `File.Open`?

I used ILSpy to decompile and look at `File.Open`.

```
public static FileStream Open(string path, FileMode mode)
{
    return File.Open(path, 
                     mode, 
                     (mode == FileMode.Append) 
                         ? FileAccess.Write 
                         : FileAccess.ReadWrite, 
                     FileShare.None);
}
```

Which calls this:

```
public static FileStream Open(string path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
{
    return new FileStream(path, mode, access, share);
}
```

And this specific `FileStream` constructor passes in `false` for the `useAsync` parameter. So, yes it appears to matter. However, you can still invoke the `async` APIs and it will still work as you'd expect.

As Hans Passant states:

> The underlying `CreateFile()` call then uses the `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` option. This enables overlapped **I/O**, a mechanism that enables asynchronous reads and writes at the winapi level.

The `FileStream` class has an `_isAsync` bool, and it means "If async IO is not supported on this platform or if this FileStream was not opened with FileOptions.Asynchronous.".

Again, you still get a `Task` that represents that asynchronous operation as you desire.

Comment: Why use a decompiler when [you can actually look at the source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/file.cs,1a53662a82db3651)?

Comment: Reference source is great and I do use it all the time, but what guarantee is there it's the update to date?  I don't actually know... either way leads to an answer.

Comment: It says it shows the source for .Net Framework 4.6.1, that should be recent enough.

Comment: So if I understand, calling the Async API methods will cause the underlying stream to be created with the correct flags even if the FileStream was not constructed with useAsync true? Because it sounds like I should be ensuring the FileStream is created using the FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED option.

Comment: @AlexHopeO'Connor, no. It will not open it with that flag -- but it will still be async.  The APIs still return the `Task` and it just works.

Answer (score 2):

[The MSDN website](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7db28s3c(v=vs.110).aspx) says:

> `useAsync`
>
> Type: [`System.Boolean`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.boolean(v=vs.110).aspx)
>
> Specifies whether to use asynchronous I/O or synchronous I/O.
>   However, note that the underlying operating system might not support
>   asynchronous I/O, so when specifying `true`, the handle might be opened
>   synchronously depending on the platform. When opened asynchronously,
>   the [BeginRead](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxt5ahzw(v=vs.71).aspx) and [BeginWrite](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t7e3td2c(v=vs.71).aspx) methods perform better on large
>   reads or writes, but they might be much slower for small reads or
>   writes. If the application is designed to take advantage of
>   asynchronous I/O, set the `useAsync` parameter to `true`. Using
>   asynchronous I/O correctly can speed up applications by as much as a
>   factor of 10, but using it without redesigning the application for
>   asynchronous I/O can decrease performance by as much as a factor of
>   10.

Comment: So it does not matter for other asynchronous IO methods like CopyToAsync?

Comment: Yes,matter for other asynchronous IO methods like CopyToAsync. but Unfortunately ,MSDN saying does not matter.

Comment: I tried this also, the result was on Win 7 x64 SP2, ALWAYS freezes at 80-99% with an exception like: "There couldn't be read any more bytes from the stream". After turning the `useAsync` flag off everything works like a charm, no freezes anymore. So it seems even MS doesn't really know what that flag does. ;)