# How to compress an base 64 image before saving it c#

Tags: c#, memory-management, image-scaling

I'm trying to create an converter that converts a base64 string to a saved image. Now I'm trying to compress the image before saving it. Is there any way to "compress" the array of bytes before I save it? I want the image to take less space on my drive (2mb to <1mb).

Example:

```
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64string);

// change the file size


// Save the image
await using FileStream fs = new(filePath, FileMode.Create);
using var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
await ms.CopyToAsync(fs);
```

I searched on the internet for some solutions but could not find any.

Comment: You can't really compress an image if it's already in a compressed format like JPEG or PNG. We need to know more about what data you're working with. Also, you don't need to use a `MemoryStream` here at all: you can write your `bytes` _directly_ to your `FileStream`. (Also, your code isn't opening the `FileStream` with the `async` flag set, so it won't actually perform overlapped IO which is necessary for true asynchrony in .NET (unless things have changed in .NET in the past few years? if not, then see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37041844/async-await-and-opening-a-filestream )